# Use Pod library for only development not for production

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have pod library which helps developer at development time but no use when the application is released, So is there anything which helps me.

1. any changes in setting at the consumer side, which consume pod library.
   or
2. any changes in setting in the pod library itself, because library is also created by me.

Comment: Make a development-only target, and add your pod dependencies only to this one?

Comment: @GregdeJ can you please describe, how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In podfile we need to add configuration to debug

`pod 'podname', :configurations => ['Debug']`

and below for release

`pod 'podname', :configurations => ['Release']`

Answer (score -1):

1. In Xcode, open the project settings, in the "Targets" list column, right click on your main iOS target and duplicate it to create one just for development.
2. In your Podfile, list up the your development-purposed pods under your new development target name. A rough example:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

target 'Your_App_Development' do
  pod 'SomeDevOnlyPod', '~> 5.6'
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i got something diffrent and easier, adding answer to my question

Comment: Creating a duplicate target is not a good way to accomplish the stated goal, especially when CocoaPods has a built in solution.

Comment: Agree, I was blindly projecting my own needs here, because I like to install both debug and release apps together on my test devices, which does require creating a target for each. I agree that when this is not needed, switching between debug and release schemes is better.